# Can nested loop be grabbed on a single loop?

Tags: c++, c

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can the code above be looped on a single loop something like this on bottom? (Though this didn't work for me.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 10, j < i; i++, j++){
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks fine like this, it is more clear than trying to garble it into something weird.

Comment: You could use while cycle, incrementing i and j manually. But it will be more difficult to read and support such code.

Comment: How you will get "\n" new line in second condition.

Comment: `i++, j++` will increment both `i` and `j` after every iteration of the loop.  This is not the same as the first snippet, which increments `j` `i` times for each value of `i` from 0 to 9.

Comment: the original code block is clear, the other code blocks are not clear.  Note: clarity is actually, for most items, more important than how tricky the code is.

Comment: See also: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683152/21-4/convert-nested-loops-into-a-single-loop.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you should look up what different operators do (and think about what *your code* should do, too).

```
for (int i = 10; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 10 <= i / 10) {
        printf("*");
    }

    if (i % 10 == 0) {
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Compensates for mine.

Comment: Note that this does more than twice as many iterations as you need, as well as more complicated arithmetic. While it shows that a nested loop *can* be replaced by a convoluted single loop, it also shows that it *shouldn't* usually be.

Comment: `(i % 10 < i / 10)` How it will work for `i=0 to 9` ?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Correct. That's why you don't see anywhere in my answer that "you should convert your nested loops to one loop". This is obviously awkward, but I wanted to show that it's possible.

Comment: @Himanshu Sorry, I've got the boundaries wrong. Should be fine now.

Comment: i think i++ is missed or what, it didnt worked for me without i++

Comment: owh, sorry, gotcha !! :)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, yaa its fine now, but will take more time. :)

Comment: please give me the program flow :S

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, This loop will work upto `i = 100` only, after that it will not working correct.

Comment: this code adds a lot more math and will generate more instructions than the original code. -1 for unnecessary complexity

Comment: @user3629249 seriously? think before you cast brain-dead, unwarranted downvotes. I didn't **advise** OP to do this, I just showed him it is possible.

Comment: @user3629249 Or do you think you should be sent to jail if you answer "yes" to the question "Is it possible to kill a human"? Also, "adds a lot more math" and "generates more instructions" are at best nonsensical arguments - for a loop of 100 iterations, it *simply doesn't matter.*

Comment: let it go :) question was mine and I respect all answers, after all you all gave time for my problem, which is great :)

Comment: this post was really useful, sorry for delay :D

Answer (score 1):

Not sensibly. You want to loop over each value of `j` for each value of `i`, which implies a nested loop. Your second example will increment both `i` and `j` after each iteration, which is very different.

In principle, you could loop a single variable from 0 to (at least) 45, and do some arithmetic to find the values of `i` and `j` from that; but that would be considerably harder to follow, and probably less efficient, so I won't suggest a way to do that.

Comment: I assume you meant "which **is** very different"…?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Yes, I started writing "is not the same", then failed to change it to "is very different".

Comment: happens quite often to me as well :P

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try, it will work fine, without any extra iterations.

```
int count=1,tmp=1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
{
    printf("*");
    if (count == i) {
        printf("\n");
        tmp++;
        count+=tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: question was if I could grab 2 loops on single loop, not to print star . Sorry to say.

Comment: after all can you please explain if statement on this code, I got messed :S

Comment: I have taken ur example of printing `*`.Here you need to value of `i`, i.e how many star you want to print(here i taken 10)? And we need to have `\n` character after printing `*` then `**` (count 3 star) the `***` (count 6 star) so I m counting like this manner, when `count==i` we are printing `\n` character. we are using `tmp++` so that every line we can print 1 extra star.

Comment: hmmmm got it probably :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i = 10, j = 0, k = 1; 
    while(j++ < i)
        (j == k && j <i) ? (printf("\n"),k+=1,j=0):printf("*");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the comma operator for this kind of thing, although your condition part is incorrect.

It should be

`for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 10 && /* perhaps || here*/ j < i; i++, j++){`

Comment: although this does something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this but its not readable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int i, j;
  for(i=0, j=0; j<i? :(printf("\n"), j=0, i++, i<10); j++) {
    printf("*");
  }
  return 0;
}
```